# Why can't I set the height of an element with ng-style?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add dynamically set the height of a `div`, but it is not successfully being set. I get the height of window and divide it by 3, but it is not working. Here is where I set the height:

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-style="height :hgt+'px'">
```

I am setting the scope variable like this:

```
 $scope.hgt = $window.innerHeight / 3;
```

But the height isn't set.

**Plunker** 
http://plnkr.co/edit/eGaPwUdPgknwDnozMJWU?p=preview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usage of `ng-style` is slightly counter-intuitive. You're attempting to use it to interpolate values, but per the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) `ng-style` takes an expression "which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys."

Thus, you might want to try:

```
$scope.hgt = { height: ($window.innerHeight / 3) + 'px' };
<div id="wrapper" ng-style="hgt">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You should put a dictionary in `ng-style` like below

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-style="{height: '{{hgt}}px'}">
  <h4 class="headerTitle">tell Mother name</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: checking wait for seconf

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}">...</some-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

`ng-style` takes an object, not a string. Here is the fix:

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-style="{ height :hgt+'px'}">
  <h4 class="headerTitle">tell Mother name</h4>
</div>
```